Using @property to clone attributes initialized from superclass
I want to create a class inheriting from a superclass that keeps track of the already initialized class attributes in the superclass. The @property decorator caught my eye and I tried to implement it (see example below).
class MyClass():

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = 'myinitialdata'

class MySubClass(MyClass):

    def __init__(self, myclass):
        super().__init__()
        self._myclass = myclass

    @property
    def data(self):
        return self._myclass.data

def main():
    new_myclass = MyClass()
    new_myclass.data = 'mynewdata'
    new_mysubclass = MySubClass(new_myclass)

    print(new_mysubclass.data)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()

However, if I want to create a property of an already initialized attribute (in the superclass) I always receive an error that the attribute cannot be set:
AttributeError: can't set attribute 'data'

The code example works if I do not initialize data in MyClass:
class MyClass():

    def __init__(self):
        # self.data = 'myinitialdata'
        pass

class MySubClass(MyClass):

    def __init__(self, myclass):
        super().__init__()
        self._myclass = myclass

    @property
    def data(self):
        return self._myclass.data

def main():
    new_myclass = MyClass()
    new_myclass.data = 'mynewdata'
    new_mysubclass = MySubClass(new_myclass)

    print(new_mysubclass.data)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()

Output:
mynewdata

Am I misusing the @property decorator here or am I missing something else in my implementation? Is the @property decorator meant to be used in that kind of scenario?
I am currently using Python 3.10.9

Why does the subclass contain a reference to a different instance of the parent class? Either it should be a wrapper or a subclass, it doesn't make much sense to be both.

The problem is when the parent assigns to self.data during super().__init__(), it uses the property defined in the subclass for itself.

You can completely redefine self.data in a subclass without using @property

Using @property in python will happen:

The return value of a method can be called without parentheses (concise), just like a simple call to an attribute
Increase encapsulation. If a property is returned directly in @property, then it is not allowed to be modified.

Once you use the data attribute in the parent class, the subclass will naturally exist, and you cannot set a read-only data
Please refer to python multiple inheritance method. The simplest explanation is if not find the attributes in subclass and find in the parent class. The parent class is always the same, and the implementation of the subclass is different.
